# Estimate Filter Coefficients from the Result of Linear Convolution with a Known Signal

Tags: dft, convolution, estimation, deconvolution, inverse-problem

If I have samples of input say x(1:500) and it passes through FIR filter with 9 taps and some unknown coefficients. The output y(1:508) is also known. The aim is to estimate the filter response in frequency domain. I know using Convolutional theorem $\hat{H} = (X^H*X)^{-1}(X^H*Y)$, but this requires fFT of full 500 samples, However I can only do fft of 128 samples at a time. How to estimate the filter response in frequency domain ?

Comment: Couldn't you simply run a 128 sample impulse at the input, then do the FFT at the output?

Comment: yep, assuming the taps aren't distributed over delays > 118, I don't see why you'd need all your input for classification. It would, however, be very interesting *why* you can't do a larger FFT. That is an [unusual problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Could you please review my answer? If something missing let me know. Else, could you please mark it?

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to build the problem in its Matrix Form.
We have the filter $ h $ which is represented by the matrix $ H $ to represent Linear Convolution operation:

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
{h}_{1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots &  & 0 \\ 
{h}_{2} & {h}_{1} & 0 & \ldots &  & 0 \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  & \vdots \\ 
0 & \ldots & {h}_{m} & {h}_{m - 1} & \ldots & {h}_{1} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & & \ldots & {h}_{m} \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

This means that the Linear Convolution is given by:

$$ \boldsymbol{y} = H \boldsymbol{x} $$

This is the equivalent of `vY = conv(vX, vH, 'full')` in MATLAB.
It is clear that for $ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $ \boldsymbol{h} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ (Namely the filter has $ m $ taps) then $ H \in \mathbb{R}^{ \left( n + m - 1 \right) \times n } $.

The above matrix $ H $ is [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).
You may be able to generate it using `GenerateToeplitzConvMatrix()` I added to my answer repository.

Bu we're after the coefficients of $ \boldsymbol{h} $. The nice thing is we can write the convolution operation as:

$$ \boldsymbol{y} = X \boldsymbol{h} $$

Where $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{\left( n + m - 1 \right) \times m} $ is still a Toeplitz Matrix since the convolution (When shape is `full` in MATLAB notation) is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

So once we have the matrix $ X $ we can solve the above equation like any other linear system:

$$ \hat{ \boldsymbol{h} } = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{h}} {\left\| X \boldsymbol{h} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} = {\left( {X}^{T} X \right)}^{-1} {X}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} $$

But since $ X $ has a special structure, being Toeplitz, there must be a way to exploit this, right?
Indeed there is, by solving it using the [Levinson Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion). You'll be able to find a solver in the code repository of this question as well (Also see my [Levinson Recursion Implementation](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/LevinsonRecursion)). The idea is similar to [Hilmar's solution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56702/128).

But I had another idea. Toeplitz Matrix are a generalization of [Circulant Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). If $ X $ was a Circulant Matrix we could use the highly efficient `fft()` function to solve the problem.

So the question is how to implement Circular Convolution using Linear Convolution.
Namely, we want to adjust the matrix $ X $ and the output $ \boldsymbol{y} $ so the will represent Circular Convolution between $ \boldsymbol{x} $ to $ \boldsymbol{h} $.

Let's say we know how build those (Let's call them $ \bar{X} $ and $ \bar{ \boldsymbol{y} } $) then we have:

$$ \bar{ \boldsymbol{y} } = \bar{X} \boldsymbol{h} $$

Yet since $ \bar{X} $ it diagonalizable by the [DFT Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) then (See [Eigen Values of Circulant Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453306)):

$$ \bar{X} = {F}^{H} \Omega F \Rightarrow \bar{ \boldsymbol{y} } = {F}^{H} \Omega F \boldsymbol{h} \Rightarrow \boldsymbol{h} = {F}^{H} {\Omega}^{-1} F \bar{\boldsymbol{y}} $$

Where $ F $ is the DFT Matrix and $ \Omega $ is a Diagonal Matrix of the Eigen Values of the matrix $ \bar{X} $. Those Eigen Values are basically the DFT Transform of $ \boldsymbol{x} $.

So basically we can solve this using the DFT (`fft()`). In MATLAB code it will be something in the lines of:

```matlab
vH = ifft(fft(vYBar) ./ fft(vX), 'symmetric');
```

The full MATLAB code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q45879 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q45879` folder).
It includes implementation of all 3 methods and one can see that each yields a perfect solution as long the system is well defined.

#### Resources

- [Circulant Preconditioned Toeplitz Least Squares Iterations](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Erchan/paper/cnp1.pdf).
- [Conjugate Gradient Methods for Toeplitz Systems](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/40770/3/TR-CS-95-07.pdf).
- [Scientific Applications of Iterative Toeplitz Solvers](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Erchan/paper/italy.pdf).
- [Iterative Methods for Linear Systems with Matrix Structure](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.8786&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
- [Least Squares and Total Least Squares Methods in Image Restoration](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-62598-4_96).
- [Fast Iterative Methods for Least Squares Estimations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02142678).
- [A Weakly Stable Algorithm for General Toeplitz Systems](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Ebrent/pd/rpb143tr.pdf).
- [Algorithms for Toeplitz Matrices with Applications to Image Deblurring](https://web.archive.org/web/20091115041852/http://etd.gsu.edu/theses/available/etd-04182008-174330/unrestricted/kimitei_symon_k_200804.pdf).
- [A Superfast Toeplitz Solver with Improved Numerical Stability](https://web.archive.org/web/20070418074240/http://saaz.cs.gsu.edu/papers/sfast.pdf).
- [Super Fast Solution of Real Positive Definite Toeplitz Systems](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Eammar/papers/amgr88.pdf).
- [Fast Solution of Toeplitz and Cauchy Like Least Squares Problems](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/050629148) (Code in [Giuseppe Rodriguez Page](http://bugs.unica.it/%7Egppe/) - [TPLS](http://bugs.unica.it/%7Egppe/software/#tpls)).
- [A Super Fast and Stable Toeplitz Direct Solver via Randomization and Hierarchically Semi Separable (HSS) Methods](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/110831982) (Code in [Jianlin Xia Page](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Exiaj/) - [HSS Software Package](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Exiaj/packages.html)).

Comment: Are you sure it is equivalent of the `full` case?

Comment: @Mark, You're right. I fix that.

Comment: Honestly I think everything besides the least squares is overkill. Wether you have 128 or 128.000 samples you only have a 9 by 9 system to solve in the end to get the last square. Uneless you have an embedded system your computer system will be ok, for instance if you use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). And if you ever need real time performance you have the [recursive least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter).

Comment: @NokiYola, Solving ill poised problem with direct LS solver will give you, in most cases, very bad results. You must have some kind of a prior on what you look for.

Comment: @Royi How is it ill posed?

Comment: @Royi also how did your method give a prior to the problem? Don't get me wrong, I learned a few things from your post and I upvoted your answer before commenting

Comment: This question specifically is just about the numerical way to solve it. In general, I wouldn't estimate the filter using LS only given noise in the system.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to easily do sliding window fft, and to get a set of outputs. That means that for the first run you will do fft on samples 1:128, on the second run fft on samples 2:129 and so on. In this way, you will get 500-128 fft outputs, each one of 128 length. After this, you may average all fft sample outputs, and get what you are looking for.
The second and a better way is possible if you have control over the filter, i.e, you can send input to your filter, the best way is to have just a single pulse running through it, and calculating fft after that.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is noise free, you really only need the first nine samples of input and output.

$$h[0] = y[0]/x[0]$$
$$h[1] = (y[1]-h[0] \cdot x[1])/x[0]$$
$$... $$
If there is noise, numerical problems, or if the initial state of the filter is unknown, you can set this up as a least square error problem in the time domani.

Answer (score 1):

Check LMS in Wikipedia, it is an iterative way, works for any size.