# Solving linear equation of discrete convolution kernels using black box model for the convolution

Tags: image-processing, convolution, linear-algebra, performance, numerical-algorithms

In [Solving inverse problem using black box implementation of the kernel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/solving-inverse-problem-using-black-box-implementation-of-the-kernel) the solution depends on solving the equations of the form:

$${\left( {H}^{T} H + \lambda {G}^{T} G \right)} x = y$$

Where $H$ and $G$ represent convolution operation of the $h$ and $g$ kernels.

Given we have a a black box implementation of the convolution by $h$ and $g$, how can we solve those equations efficiently?

Those forms are very common in many image processing algorithms and solving them by the matrix representation is not efficient.

Comment: The inverse operation is called deconvolution. Classical method are Richardson-Lucy and Iterative Constrained Tikhonov-Miller. There are some newer solutions, such as Fast Iterative Shrinkage Thresholding (FISTA).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, If you look at the context he used, the idea is as following, if you have a kernel $ \boldsymbol{h} $ and $ \boldsymbol{g} $, how do you apply above fast using convolution operations.

Comment: @Royi If you look up the above methods, they're always implemented using the FFT. There are lots of implementations out there to use (or just to look at if OP insists in implementing it themselves).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, If you look on the context of the answer it is something like the FISTA model (TV regularization) yet with ADMM which is even faster than the accelerated proximal gradient descent in FISTA.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an easy question, not because ideas are complex but since the details matter a lot.

As I wrote in my answer in the question [Solving Inverse Problem Using Black Box Implementation of the Convolution Kernel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87500), the issue is defining how to handle the boundaries (See [The Different Solutions for Filter Coefficients Estimation for Periodic Convolution and Full Convolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87406)). This is super important for images.

#### Matrix Case

In all cases, for this equation:

$$ {\left( {H}^{T} H + \lambda {G}^{T} G \right)} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y} \Leftrightarrow A \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y} $$

Can be solved using sparse solvers taking advantage of the sparsity pattern of the matrices and the matrix being symmetric positive definite.

This will work for any variant of the convolution.
Though we have 2 options, direct solvers and iterative ones.

The iterative ones allow us taking advantage of the convolution black box as they usually require applying the operator $ A $. Many iterative solvers require $ {A}^{T} $ but if they do, it means they don't model it as a symmetric operator. Hence it means they are not optimal. So stick with those assuming symmetric operator, hence require $ A $ only.

Now the question, how to implement $ A $ efficiently?

#### Periodic / Cyclic Boundary Conditions

If we assume that the $ \ast $ (Convolution) is applied using cyclic boundary convolution we can apply everything in frequency domain.
I wrote many answer about it, you may look at them:

- [Applying Convolution in Frequency Domain by Element Wise Multiplication on Time Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/80687).
- [Dealing with the Cyclic Boundary Conditions of Frequency Domain Convolution in Order to Apply Linear Convolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78918).
- [Circular Convolution Matrix of $ {H}^{T} H $](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56709).
- [The Matrix Form of a 2D Circular Convolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81949).
- [Least Squares Solution Using the DFT vs Wiener Hopf Equations](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87326).
- [Estimate Filter Coefficients from the Result of Linear Convolution with a Known Signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45879).
- [Strategy / Method for Implementation of the Fastest 1D Linear Convolution / Correlation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52760).
- [Show Equivalence Between Multiplication in Time Domain to Convolution in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/64870).
- [Replicate MATLAB's `conv2()` in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74803).

#### The Convolution of Type `full` / `same` / `valid`

For the other convolution types (I Use the lingo of MATLAB's convolution functions, such as [`conv2()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)) things are trickier.

I created the matrix $ {H}^{T} H $ for the different convolution shapes from the same 3 coefficients kernel applied on 5 samples signal:

[image]

As one can see, while all cases generates a `5x5` matrix, yet only the `full` case generates a [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).
Hence, only this case can be represented by a convolution kernel with some convolution type.

##### General Solution

We can always apply each matrix by itself. Something like:

$$ {\left( {H}^{T} H + \lambda {G}^{T} G \right)} \boldsymbol{x} = {H}^{T} \left( H \boldsymbol{x} \right) + \lambda {G}^{H} \left( G \boldsymbol{x} \right) $$

So $ H \boldsymbol{x} $ / $ G \boldsymbol{x} $ is just applying the convolution, what about $ {H}^{T} \boldsymbol{z} $ / $ {G}^{T} \boldsymbol{z} $?
Well, we can have a recipe per case, where the adjoint is done by the flipped kernel:

- Convolution Type `full` -> Correlation type `valid`.
- Convolution Type `same` -> Correlation type `same`.
- Convolution Type `valid` -> Correlation type `full`.

Now we can apply all of the above one by one.

##### Optimized Solution for `full`

As we can see, in case our convolution is of type `full` the normal matrix $ {H}^{T} H $ is a Toeplitz Matrix, so we can generate the composite operation using a single kernel convolution.

#### Results

I implemented all cases above and using Conjugate Gradient I got the following results for 1D:

[image]

As can be seen, we can get the same results using the iterative method.
This method only applies convolution operations and doesn't require the matrix form.

#### Some Other Resources

- [Estimating Convolution Input Under the Assumption of Sparsity and Constant Non Zero Values Using Compressive Sensing Approach](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66778).

Comment: You can get around the periodic boundary condition of the FFT-based convolution by simply padding the image a bit. This is a fairly standard procedure, I think?

Comment: $H^TH$ translates to $H^*H = |H|^2$ if $H$ is the Fourier transform of the kernel, rather than the convolution matrix.

Comment: I wrote that I don't take care of the DFT in this answer as I wrote about it in many other places (I linked, some include the extension trick). I am not sure it will be faster from using the `full` method. I am working on extending the answer.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Does you library have something like that pre defined as a function? I am talking about generating this in Fourier domain using the proper padding and afterwards proper extraction of the signals?

Comment: There’s several deconvolution algorithms, they all use the Fourier domain for convolution using proper padding etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, OK. Let's see if the OP is interested in it. Then I might compare high level results to your code (I read it has Python / MATLAB wrapper, I don't "speak" `C++` :)).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I found that 2 years ago I implemented this in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74803. I still don't see the way to apply the whole operator in frequency for the case of non `full` convolution. I'd argue it can not be done as the operators don't even generate a Toeplitz Matrix. Are you sure you can apply the whole operator $ {\left( {H}^{T} H + \lambda {G}^{T} G \right)} $ at once for the case of `valid` or `same` convolution operator?

Comment: Neither of those three methods are really useful in image processing. `valid` is the only sensical method, but it assumes pixels outside the frame are 0, which usually causes strong edge effects. It is better to use a different boundary condition, such as mirroring. Still, I don’t see the difference between that compound operator and any other convolution operation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Working with boundary (I usually prefer `replicate`) is equivalent to padding and then `valid` convolution. This is the context it will work. Actually the latest crop of the pre deep learning methods usually assumed `valid` convolution. Pay attention that the matrix of the boundaries will not generate a Toeplitz / Block Toeplitz matrix which again can not be approximated, even with padding, in frequency. So it means you need to actually pad and work with the new one. For `full` convolution, no problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, By the way `valid` is not equivalent to `zero` boundary, it is `full` which is equivalent to `zero` boundary conditions.

Comment: I meant “same” is the only sensical method — Typo! You need the output to be the same size as the input more often than not.

Comment: Anyway, the convolution matrix is a great way to think about the problem, and figure out optimization schemes, but it’s not a good way to implement anything. And the implementation doesn’t need to match what the matrix does at the edges, that is totally uninteresting. In an actual implementation you handle the edges in the way that gives them least impact on the result. In an ideal world, the images are infinite in size and we don’t need to deal with the edges. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I am aware of the concept and have worked by it. Still, without actually padding the data which means allocations, I don't see how you can do this in frequency domain unless you assume `cyclic` or `full` convolution.

Comment: Regarding the boundaries, I think differently. How we model them has a great effect on the deconvolution. Hence we must handle them carefully which is why, to my knowledge, the most advanced methods don't solve those equations in frequency domain. See for instance: https://i.imgur.com/dE94Xjk.png. Once you have the mask, the composition can not be calculated in frequency (Unless you do some  tricks, for another time).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I explained what I mean in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87582. I'd be happy for you feedback.

Comment: Yes, how you handle the boundary has a very big effect on the result. But the convolution we’re trying to undo was applied to a continuous-domain to image which was then windowed and sampled. The convolution “mode” as defined in MATLAB is not part of the deconvolution problem, though the image edge is an additional problem that needs to be overcome.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Totally agree. But at the end, we need to model something. From the same reasoning you present, I think the bets model was to use `valid`. Then the "unknown" part has to be estimated (Then will be discarded).

Comment: Sure, but discard the image edges only at the very end, not at every convolution in the iterative processes. The longer you iterate, the less result you’re left with!!!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Even if it iterative, you usually pad, convolution with `valid` then the output is of the same dimensions.

Comment: Right, so then you apply a different boundary condition than what is provided by `conv`. That is the same as using “same” with a better padding than zeros. In an iterative process, it is best to pad once, and not crop until the very end. The padding contains a bit of information after the convolution, throwing that away after each step is not as good as keeping until the end.